# Solving and numerical integrated equation and iteration

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following expresion that I can evaluate (finally):

$$V(R)=\frac{4867}{R^2}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{200000E^{-0.36k^2}r Sin[kr]Sin[kR]dr dk}{(120000+E^{2r})k^2R}}+\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1.6*10^7E^{-0.36k^2}(100+22k^2+k^4)r Sin[kr]Sin[kR])dr dk}{(120000+E^{2r})(16+k^2)(7+k^2)R}}$$

for which I take (by the moment) lambda equal to one. As you can imagine, the integrals have to be made numerically and, at most, one can obtain a table, for which I used the next code:

```
V[R_]= Table[{R,4867/R^2+
NIntegrate[(200000*Exp[-0.36k^2]*r*Sin[k r]*Sin[k 
R])/((120000+Exp[2r])k^2*R)+
(-1.6*10^7*Exp[-0.36k^2](100+22k^2+k^4)*r*Sin[k r]*
Sin[k R])/((120000+Exp[2r])(16+k^2)(7+k^2)R),{k,0,Infinity},{r,0,Infinity},
Method->{Automatic,"SymbolicProcessing"->0},PrecisionGoal->4,AccuracyGoal-
>5]},{R,0.01,50,0.1}]
```

And then I obtain this lovely plot (I just take some range of the plot):

[image]

As you can see, there is an horizontal line which is y=6 and here is when my problems show up: The red line cuts three points of the blue line; I have to find those points, that is, solving the equation V(R)=y, then I have to put the first two points in the next equation:

$$\int_{R1}^{R2}{\sqrt{0.2|V(R)-y|}}-10\pi=0$$

however, this equation will not be correct for lambda=1 (which I assumed in first place) !!!. One procedure I can follow to fit the last equation and the equation V(R)=y at the same time, is to slowly vary the parameter lambda in the first integral (say, from 0.7 in steps of 0.01) , then find the points and put the values in the last equation until the integral is almost 10 pi. But I don't know how to do such thing efficiently in Mathematica !! Initially, I can find the points using a Interpolation function and after that put those points in the last expression but I would spend one week varying the lambda factor 0.01 each and repeating the process. I tried with Do and Catch comands but I cannot create a suitable loop. Can anybody please help me with this? I would really appreciate it :D

Comment: Is it possible that your code has a few typos? (Shouldn't `kr`/`kR` be `k r`/`k R`?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.  From your plot, $V(R) < 0$ between $R_1$ and $R_2$, so the square root is going to give us imaginary values.   Can we use $\sqrt{0.2(y-V(R))}$ as the integrand?

Comment: I have already correct the typos here, because I don't have them in my code Mathe172. The potential is negative only for y<0, and in this case , y>0. The negative part of the potential represents the strong interaction in a decay.

Comment: And you right LouisB. The argument inside square root is in absolute value !!! that's important :D